# how to pass custom values in uploadify

Tags: php, html, uploadify

in uploadify How to pass user input values to uploadify.php 
here is my code:

```
           $(function() {

    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'buttonText' : 'BROWSE...',
    'method'   : 'post', 
    'height'   : 50, 
    'buttonCursor' : 'hand',
    'fileSizeLimit' : '100KB', 
    'formData' : {
    'title' :$('input:text[name:title]').val(),
    'about' :$('input:text[name:about]').val() },
    'auto'     : false,
    'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
    'checkExisting' : 'check-exists.php',
    'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
    'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
    $("#message").css("display","block");
    $("#message").text("upload process completed successfully");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#message').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000);
    }, 

    'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
       alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
    }  
});



    });
    </script>
    </head>
<?php include("includes/connection.php");?>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Photogallery</h1>
     <?php  include("includes/navigation.php"); ?>
            </div><!--header-->

            <div id="content">

                <div id="left">

<div id="message">
</div>
<?php

 ?>     

 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <P>Title:</P>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" name="title" id="idtitle" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>About:</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p><input type="text" value="" name="about"  />  </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Select Photos you want to Upload
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>           


<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('cancel')">Cancel First File</a> | <a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('cancel', '*')">Clear the Queue</a> | <a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload', '*')">Upload the Files</a>



                </div><!--left-->
```

Here is my uplodify.php file

```
   <?php
require_once("includes/connection.php");

$targetFolder = '/workbench/sudeepc/photogallery/uploads' ; 
     $title=$_POST['title'];
     // $title="testtitle";
     $about=$_POST['about'];    
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);



    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

$query="INSERT INTO `photo` ( `id` , `path` , `uname` , `title` , `about` , `date` )
VALUES ('','${targetFile}','uname','${title}','${about}',now())";       

 /*
 $query="INSERT INTO `photo` ( `id` , `path` , `uname` )
 VALUES ( '','${targetFile}', '${title}');";
 */
 mysql_query($query,$connection);


    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

I want to pass title as well as about for each uploads and when user select more than one picture user can enter title and about for each one. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: now the database entry is null.

Comment: is there any way to print that query in browser ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. How to pass custom values in uploadify:

`'formData': { 'userid': $("#uid").val(), 'taskid': $("#tid").val(), 'guid': $("#guid").val() },`

1. Is there any way to get the number of image in upload queue? - onDialogClose you have access to queue like this:

`'onDialogClose': function(queueData) {
      alert(queueData.filesQueued + ' files were queued of ' + queueData.filesSelected + ' selected files. There are ' + queueData.queueLength + ' total files in the queue.');
            },`

Answer (score 3):

To pass custom values use [formData](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/formdata-2/)

Then you can access it on PHP `$_POST['someKey']`

```
 ...
 'formData'         : {
     'title' : $('input:text[name:title]').val(),
     'about' : $('input:text[name:about]').val(),
      ...
  },
 ..
```

To check number of files being uploaded, add this callback:

```
  ...
  onDialogClose : function() {
      console.log(this.queueData.filesQueued);
  },
  ...
```

Comment: 'formData':{
    'title' : $('#idtitle').val() },   When i try this i am getting null value in uploadify.php

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. HOw to resolve multiple upload case?

Comment: is there any way to get the number of image in upload queue.So that i can display title text box and about text box for each one.

Comment: Updated answer please checkout

Comment: 'formData' : {
    'title' :$('input:text[name:title]').val(),
    'about' :$('input:text[name:about]').val() },i don't know why  this is not working now