# Cannot pass values to uploadify using onuploadstart and formdata

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

When I add the *formData* part `'formData' : {'gallery_choice' : 'EMPTY'}` the code still works, but I want to change *'EMPTY'* to the chosen gallery with PHP using `<?php $GLOBALS['gallery_choice'] ?>` or whatever else works (but the value I need is saved as this global).

When I add the *onUploadStart* part (added in the code section below), the **uploadify.swf** file stops working and I'm presented with the fall back option (a boring HTML "Choose File" button) instead of the fancy flash button - what am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        //'auto'     : false,
        'formData' : {'gallery_choice' : 'EMPTY'},
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
        'queueSizeLimit' : 10,
        'width'    : 150,
        'height'   : 20,
        'buttonText' : 'V&aelig;lg Filer',
        'checkExisting' : '/check-exists.php',
        'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
        'fileSizeLimit' : '400KB',
        //'uploadLimit' : 20
        // Put your options here
        'overrideEvents' : ['onSelectError','onDialogClose','onUploadStart'],
        'onUploadStart' : function(file){
                    $('#file_upload').uploadify('settings','gallery_choice','TEMP'});
                    },
        'onSelectError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg) {
          switch(errorCode) {    
          case 110:
            alert('ALERT! File is to big! The File: "' + file.name + '" is larger than the maximum size of 400KB! The file was not uploaded!');       
          break;
          case 130:
            alert('ALERT! INCORRECT FILE TYPE! The file: "' + file.name + '" is not of the allowed type (.jpg, .png eller .gif)! The file was not uploaded!');
          break;
          case 120:
            alert('ALERT! THE FILE IS EMPTY! The file: "' + file.name + '" is empty (0 bytes)! The file was not uploaded!');
          break;          
          default:
            alert('ALERT! The file: "' + file.name + '" made an error with the error code: ' + errorCode + ', as well as the following message: ' + errorMsg + '  The file was not uploaded!!');     
          }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

In case anyone wants it, here is also the **uploadify.php** file:

```
<?php
// Define a destination from user choice
if(isset($_GET['gallery_choice'])){
    $targetFolder = 'uploads/' . $_GET['gallery_choice'] . '/';
}else
    $targetFolder = 'uploads/TEMP/';

//$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root
//$targetFolder = 'uploads/';
//$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) /*&& $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken*/) {
    //$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    //$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    //$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"], $targetFolder . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]);
        echo '1';
    } else {
         echo '0';        
    }

    /*
    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
    */
}
?>
```

I've Googled and Stack-Overflowed, but not found a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911279/how-to-pass-custom-values-in-uploadify

Comment: @Muhammad Usman
While you could argue that we had a similar problem in not being able to successfully pass information to Uploadify.php, the reasons for our failings are different and in fact I had two issues to solve and looking at the above question you posted did not help me. Thanx anyhow though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I experienced with the Flash button not turning up was due to this line `'formData' : {'gallery_choice' : 'EMPTY'},`

When I changed it to `'formData' : {'gallery_choice' : '<?php echo $GLOBALS['gallery_choice']; ?>'},`
it started working and once I figured out to use **$_POST** instead of **$_GET** in my *Uploadify.php*, it started working - this is the update to Uploadify.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['gallery_choice'])){
    $targetFolder = 'uploads/' . $_POST['gallery_choice'] . '/';
}else
    $targetFolder = 'uploads/TEMP/';
```